# Rails: How can I access "request" within lib folder class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, websocket

I am trying to implement websocket via Faye Websocket.

Until so far, I am able to implement websocket middleware on backend and client JS to open websocket and send and receive data on both sides..

Now on the rails backend, I am processing the websocket message received via my custom class inside lib folder. I would like to fetch client IP address (planing to add user_agent info when I solve fetching IP address) via "request.remote_ip" within myClass in lib folder,unfortunately it is not possible to access it directly.

Can you please guide me how I can access "request" object within lib folder?

lib/myClass.rb

```
class myClass
  ip_address = request.remote_ip


end

#<NameError: undefined local variable or method `request' for #<myClass:0x0055c6fb18d860>
Did you mean?  require>
```

Comment: pass `request` from controller as parameter to library

Comment: I am not calling the custom class method from controller. I am trying to utilize websocket.. And myClass is processing message received via websocket. I also do not prefer to send client IP within websocket which  may be manupulated

Comment: Can you add more context, for example where the class is called and when the call is triggered?

Comment: I have Faye::Websocket middleware which is listening websocket connections. Inside the middleware code, I call myClass with the socket messages as the parameters

Answer (score 0):

Use like that:-

In `lib/my_class.rb`

```
class MyClass < Struct.new(:request)
  def self.call(request)
    new(request).call
  end

  def call
    ip_address = request.remote_ip
  end
end
```

And from `some_controller`:-

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def some_method
    MyClass.call(request)
  end
end
```

Comment: since I am not calling from ApplicationController it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

I have found that, Faye Websocket object also stores environmental variables which includes the client IP address and user agent info I was looking for.

```
  user_agent: socket.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],
  ip_address: socket.env["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

So instead of request object, I fetched these info from Faye websocket object directly.